# asp.net insertCommand resulting in NULL values

Tags: asp.net, null, sql-insert

I have two listboxes whose values are sent into a TableC via a button.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionDataBase %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] + ' (' + [CNbr] + ')' AS FullName, [CNbr] AS CNum FROM [TableA] ORDER BY [Name]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:ListBox ID="lst1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sql1" DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="CNum" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:ListBox>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionDataBase %>"  
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [TableB] ([CNbr], [RDate]) VALUES (@CNbr, @RDate)" 
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CNbr" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="RDate" Type="DateTime" />
        </InsertParameters>

        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibnCheckOutBtn" runat="server" 
            ImageUrl="./images/vidCheckOutButton.png" onclick="ibnCheckOutBtn_Click"   />
```

ASPX.CS file:

```
protected void ibnBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    sql2.Insert();
}
```

I don't really know C# and my class doesn't cover most C#, so I am looking for a solution that doesn't use a lot of behind-code.  The error I get is:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CNbr', table 'TableB'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.  The statement has been terminated.

However, nulls should not occur because the values are taken from a fully populated listbox.  Help?

Comment: The variable has to have the same name. Either use CNbr or cnum, but not both. [CNbr] AS CNum

Comment: Where did all the other posts go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to assign the values to sql2 insert parameters in a similar way as follows:

```
protected void ibnBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    sql2.InsertParameters["CNbr"].DefaultValue = this.FindControl("lst1").SelectedValue;
    sql2.InsertParameters["RDate"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    sql2.Insert();
}
```

Comment: Hey,I get a red squiggly line under .SelectedValue; , and I don't know what is it's cause.

Comment: change this.FindControl("lst1").SelectedValue; to ((ListBox)this.FindControl("lst1")).SelectedValue;. I forgot the cast. Depending on your aspx page structure, you might also need to adjust how you 'find' the listbox if FindControl does not work.